# Literal and metaphorical translation of "duende"

Tags: traducción, definiciones

I have read that *duende* can mean both a mythical creature or, metaphorically, a kind of magical sensation to something. What exactly does *duende* refer to in both senses? How would both of these senses be best translated to English?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you said, *Duende* has two basic meanings:

- **Mythical Creature** Traditionally it refers to a mischievous *spirit that inhabits a house*. Now it's also used to refer to small creatures with magical powers; they usually are very skinny, have big heads, big eyes and long ears (also, Santa's Helpers are called "Duendes de Santa Claus").
- **Feeling** It's almost exclusively used in Flamenco. It's a *mysterious sensation that is very hard to define*. More [here](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flamenco#Duende).

Over all, it's a very complex word, it has a lot of history, and can be used in several sentences, and mean something different in each one, but it's always something special.

From the [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=duende) and [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duende)

Comment: +1 Now I know that `duende` was also used to signify a feeling. Until now, I had never heard the word used in a different context other than the mythical creature.

Answer (score 3):

There are several words that can work as a translation for *duende*:

- [Goblin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goblin)
- [Leprechaun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leprechaun) (Personally I always think about this when I imagine a *duende*)
- [Gremlin](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gremlin)

They may not be an "exact" translation, as the folklore in each region is different and the characteristics of these mythological beings can vary slightly.

For the second meaning, I found "to have charm" as a possible English translation [for "tener duende"](https://es.pons.com/traducci%C3%B3n?q=duende&l=enes&in=&lf=en).