# Names of mythical beings/creatures

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario

[Another question I asked](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1153/literal-and-metaphorical-translation-of-duende) made me realize that English has many names for mythical beings. Many of these can refer to both a historical myth or superstition as well as a more modern definition (in fiction, gaming, movies, etc.), but most of them clearly refer to a particular type of mythical creature.

Mythical creatures I can think of would include the following. Do these have direct translations in Spanish? If not, what words for mythical beings exist in Spanish and what types of creatures do they refer to?

- elf
- dwarf
- goblin
- pixie
- fairy
- dragon
- mermaid
- unicorn
- leprechaun
- centaur
- gnome
- orc
- troll
- werewolf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, they all refer to mythical beings and, AFAIK, **most** of them have direct spanish translations:

> **Elf**: Elfo
>
> **Dwarf**: Enano
>
> **Goblin**: Trasgo (Spain) or Trauco (Chile)
>
> **Fairy**: Hada
>
> **Pixie**: Pixie (consider a kind of fairy)
>
> **Dragon**: Dragón
>
> **Mermaid**: Sirena
>
> **Unicorn**: Unicornio
>
> **Leprechaun**: Duende
>
> **Centaur**: Centauro
>
> **Gnome**: Gnomo
>
> **Orc**: Orco
>
> **Troll**: Trol
>
> **Werewolf**: Hombre lobo / Licántropo

Other creatures:

> **Cyclops**: Cíclope
>
> **Nymph**: Ninfa
>
> **Chimera**: Quimera
>
> **Ogre**: Ogro
>
> **Hobbit**: Hobbit
>
> **Gremlin**: Gremlin
>
> **Kraken**: Kraken
>
> **Golem**: Golem
>
> **Medusa**: Medusa

Damn! I love mythology :)

Comment: +1 for *trol* (with plural *troles* like *sol*,*soles*). 99% of natives still use *troll*.

Comment: +1 Excellent job. I could have not translated many of those to Spanish.

Comment: +1 Great answer. I would add 'licántropo' as a translation to werewolf