# Are there any words in Spanish that are very difficult to translate to English?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

There seem to be many words (especially technical ones) in English that don't directly translate to a single word in Spanish. What about in the other direction: are there any words in Spanish that are notoriously difficult to translate into English (in other words, they can't be fully expressed in English in just a couple words)?

Comment: Are you looking for a list of such words? In that case, it can be **very** long and complicated. Can you narrow it a bit? Words don't always translate 1:1, but that translation depends on the context. Writing a comprehensive list here, taking into account all of that is basically impossible.

Comment: @Alenanno: Nope, not looking for an exhaustive list. Just wondering if there are *any* Spanish words that are *very difficult* to translate (for example, it would take a whole sentence to convey their meaning in English rather than a few words).

Comment: I still have the impression it's still long... I can give you 5 or 6 examples, but another user might come with other examples, so unless I go through a dictionary, I doubt you can do it in a fairly short time... Unless there is a resource somewhere, of course. :)

Comment: The names of products or meals from the country are usually quite difficult to translate, for instance: "chorizo" or "salchichón".

Comment: @Javi: Ah, good point. Maybe then to narrow the list we should exclude any food dishes, cultural traditions, etc. I'm thinking of standard nouns, adjectives, etc. that describe a concept difficult to express in English.

Comment: Ops, I voted for NARQ, but I meant **not constructive**. As you see the answers provide each different info. I don't think this is a question fit to the Q&A sites.

Comment: I don't think this is a good question.  1) It sounds like a list question. 2) Even if you're asking only for a simple "yes/no" question, how do you define "very difficult?" I think the criteria provided (requires more than a couple English words) isn't a good criteria, as it should be easy to come up with many words that fit into this category. As someone pointed out, many nouns fall into this category, as will names of events, and many adjectives.

Comment: @Javi: "chorizo" is a good example, especially because it may have a different meaning depending on the country. See http://english.stackexchange.com/q/6107/1720.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently *duende*.  I always thought it just had the *elf* connotation.

[What is the hardest word to translate from Spanish?](http://hotword.dictionary.com/duende/)

Comment: I think it's much more difficult to translate it when it means "a feeling of inspiration" like in flamenco rather than when it means the mythical creature. It's even difficult to define it in Spanish. Related answer: http://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1162/105

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion it's the word

> Sinvergüenza

Lots of possible translations, lots of connotations.

Comment: Isn't it basically variations of _shameless person_ dependent on context?

Comment: I've come across lots of other translations such as: crook, scoundrel, cheeky etc..
I've heard it in contexts where the person is calling someone a sinvergüenza to insult them using one of the above translations or 'shameless' as you mentioned.
Also I've heard it being used as a friendly sort of 'shameless' used to describe a kind of outgoing person who's not embarrassed by anything.

Answer (score -1):

I think so. *Cursi* and *quedar* (like in "hemos quedado a las seis") come to mind.

Cursi is close in meaning to cheesy, corny and tacky, but also has a connotation of baroquely embellished, overdone and pretentious that these terms do not convey.

Quedar, at least in the sense that we use it in Spain, describes an intention. If I say that "hemos quedado a las seis", it means that my friends and I have agreed to meet at six. It could be roughly translated as "agree to meet".

Comment: Isn't *cursi* "cheesy" or "corny"? Isn't *quedado* "stayed"?

Comment: quedar may be translated as "meet": We have met at 6 o'clock

Comment: No to both. I am editing my answer to clarify.

Comment: I might suggest *kitsch* as a translation of *cursi* that covers some of the other aspects you listed.

Comment: @hippietrail: No. Kitsch id usted in Spanish too, but that's something else. Kitsch is ugly and pretentious but not necessarily sweet to the extreme, which cursi always is.