# Una pregunta con "duende": origen de la acepción relativa al sentimiento

Tags: etimología, significado, españa, sustantivos

En [Literal and metaphorical translation of "duende"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1153/12637) ya se avanzó que el término *duende*, cuando se refiere a la sensación, es un término que se usa casi exclusivamente en el mundo del flamenco. La verdad es que es un término muy difícil de definir. Si tenéis la ocasión de hablar con un sevillano, preguntadle si os sabe definir esta palabra y veréis cómo se bloquea. Acabará diciendo que eso es "algo que no se puede describir". Y puede que no le falte razón. La RAE lo define como:

> [**duende**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EEmriFA)
>
> 2. m. Encanto misterioso e inefable.

Nótese que "inefable" significa "que no se puede explicar con palabras", de ahí que al sevillano no le falte razón. Sin embargo, lo que no he podido encontrar es el origen de esa acepción. Según la RAE, la etimología de la misma es muy curiosa:

> De *duen de [casa]* 'dueño de [la casa]'.

Fascinante. Y es verdad, en textos antiguos se pueden encontrar cosas como:

> *Et de aquj proçeden por la mayor parte que muchas personas dizen que veen aytones & duen de casa & trasgo.*
>
> Lope de Barrientos, "Tratado del dormir y despertar y soñar.", 1445 (España).

Por tanto, la palabra que describe al espíritu fantástico viene de "dueño de", dado que se dice que suele habitar las casas y se les considera los verdaderos dueños de las mismas. Pero en algún momento, la palabra *duende*, que evoca un ser fantástico y misterioso, pasó a denominar otro tipo de misterio: el que poseen aquellas personas con una determinada habilidad especial para encandilar con su arte. Y ahí es donde me quiero detener:

- ¿Es eso así? ¿Fue la acepción de "espíritu fantástico" la que provocó la aparición de la acepción como sentimiento? ¿O fue casualidad?
- ¿Hacia qué año se comienza a hablar del "duende" como un sentimiento? ¿Se puede determinar su origen exacto?

Os dejo con la letra de una conocida canción:

> Sevilla tiene un color especial,
>   Sevilla sigue teniendo su duende,
>   me sigue oliendo a azahar,
>   me gusta estar con su gente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según indica el [*NTLLE*](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-1992/nuevo-tesoro-lexicografico), la primera vez que "duende" aparece como "encanto misterioso e inefable" es bastante reciente, en 1956; por otra parte, en 1791 apareció por primera vez, y estuvo en el diccionario hasta hace no mucho, la acepción de "tener uno duende" como

> Modo de hablar con que se explica que uno trae en la imaginación
>   alguna especie que le inquieta.

Es obvio que la acepción que nos interesa se usa desde hace mucho antes que su introducción en el diccionario; de lo contrario, Federico García Lorca no habría podido dar, en 1933, su conferencia [*Teoría y juego del duende*](https://es.wikisource.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_y_juego_del_duende); pero no pude encontrar fuentes que indiquen una fecha concreta.

En cuanto a la etimología, encontré dos teorías. La primera es la que postula el artículo ["Una teoria sul gioco del duende & F. Garcia Lorca, Gioco e teoria del duende"](http://www.academia.edu/12610206/Una_teoria_sul_gioco_del_duende_and_F._Garcia_Lorca_Gioco_e_teoria_del_duende_Studi_INterculturali_2_2013_), por Gianni Ferracuti (*Studi interculturali* Nº 2, 2013), que dice más o menos que

> El paso entre el duende como ser y el duende flamenco podría
>   representarlo el adjetivo "aduendado", ya aplicado a una persona por
>   Cervantes [mencionado con anterioridad: "Quítenme de allí aquel
>   músico, si no voto á Dios que me vaya sin ver mas figura; valgate el
>   diablo por músico aduendado, y que hace de menudear sin citola, y sin
>   son".]; se puede imaginar que un lugar está "aduendado", poseído por
>   un duende, y que, por metáfora, se llega a hablar de una persona
>   "aduendada", o que "tiene duende", en el sentido arriba indicado.
>   (...) Me interesa además hacer notar que, en la expresión "tener
>   duende" que aparece también en el contexto de Lorca, hay un individuo
>   que *tiene* un duende, y no un duende que posee al individuo: como
>   habrá modo de aclarar más adelante, el artista "aduendado" no está
>   poseído.

La otra explicación, que parece más convincente, es la que figura en el texto (no sé si será una tesis) [*Teoría del duende: Concepto popular vinculado a la experiencia estética del éxtasis*](https://riunet.upv.es/bitstream/handle/10251/35390/TFM%20Teor%C3%ADa%20del%20duende.pdf?sequence=1), de Odette Fajardo Montaño (Universidad Politécnica de Valencia, 2013):

> Este término parece tener su raíz más directa del vocablo *duquende*
>   que proviene del caló, lengua gitana con variantes dependiendo de los
>   lugares donde el pueblo gitano se ha asentado. George Borrow, escritor
>   e investigador inglés que en el siglo XIX realizó viajes a España para
>   conocer la cultura gitana, se refiere en su libro [*Zincali, Gypsies of
>   Spain*](https://archive.org/stream/zincali00unkngoog#page/n212/mode/2up) a la palabra *duquende*, que significa espíritu, “Duénde”.
>   Asimismo, afirma que el origen de la palabra procede del vocablo
>   gitano ruso *Dook*, que a su vez proviene de la palabra *Dhúka*.
>   Existe además la palabra *duquendio* que significa según Borrow
>   “maestro, hombre principal entre los gitanos” y en esto coincide en
>   parte con R. Campuzano, quien en su diccionario de *Orijen, usos y
>   costumbres de los jitanos*, define *duquendió* como, “maestro, el que
>   enseña ciencia o arte”. (...) En tanto, la palabra *duquelas*, que
>   evidentemente comparte un origen etimológico con la palabra
>   *duquende*, tiene un significado que comúnmente se refiere a las “penas” o “dolores”, George Borrow define a la palabra *duquip* como
>   dolor. Estas relaciones semánticas resultan interesantes si
>   consideramos el hecho —que veremos más adelante— de que el duende está
>   ligado al dolor y a la vulnerabilidad. (...)
>
> Ahora volviendo al
>   origen etimológico del término duende, Walter Starkie, hispanista
>   irlandés que siguió los pasos de Borrow, afirma en su [*Raggle-Taggle*](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.208611/2015.208611.Raggle-Taggle#page/n245/mode/2up)
>   que *dukh* (palabra que proviene de la lengua gitana de Rusia), es un
>   espíritu dionisíaco que produce un “raro frenesí orgiástico” que los
>   “posee de tal manera que llegan a ser como Bacantes de Eurípides en
>   sus “fiestas” musicales. Esta última definición coincide en gran
>   medida con la astuta mirada de García Lorca, que contrapone el
>   concepto de duende con el de ángel y musa.

Con lo cual, según esa explicación, el término vendría de "espíritu", pero no del lado que suponíamos; es decir, no del español "duen de [casa]", sino del habla gitana.

Comment: Personalmente me inclino más a creer la primera teoría, me parece más plausible. Sin embargo, sí que es cierto que hay registros sobre el término "duquende" del caló: la segunda teoría suena también muy interesante. Buscando por Internet veo que el ruso _dook_ (espíritu) proviene a su vez de una palabra del sáncrito que significa "aire". ¡Estupenda tu respuesta!

Comment: [Esta pregunta](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/37846/19545) en History creo que te viene como anillo al dedo, JMVanPelt :)